# Volume of a Triangle Rotated about Different Lines

Tags: geometry, volume

Let's say I have a triangle formed bound by the x/y axes and the line $y=1-x$.
Say I rotate this triangle about the y-axis, forming a cone with $r=1$ and $h=1$. 
$v=\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2h$, so $v=\frac{\pi}{3}$ $u^3$.
Say I also rotate the original triangle about the line $x=1$, forming a "banked incline" whose volume is given by $v=\pi r^2h- \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2h$ or $v=\frac{2}{3} \pi r^2h$, so $v=\frac{2}{3} \pi$ $u^3$.
My question is this: why are the volumes of the solids different *conceptually*? I understand why this is true mathematically (for instance, the same problem can be done through integration), but lack the intuition behind this truth. The way I'm mistakenly thinking about this is that since both solids share the same cross-sectionional area no matter where you slice them, their volumes should also be identical, but clearly that's wrong.

Comment: The "intuition behind this truth" should be obvious if you spent at least an hour thinking carefully about it. But you also acknowledge that your "same cross-sectional area" idea as clearly wrong, so let me tell you exactly why. If the cross-sectional area sweeps out a region in a way that the cross-section **remains parallel** to the initial one all the way, then the volume is the area of that cross-section times the **perpendicular distance** swept out by it. It is clearly not the case with a **rotating** cross-section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing in *Wolfram Mathematica 12.0*:

```
cone1 = ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[v], u Sin[v], 1 - u}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2π},
                         Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.2]]];

cone2 = ParametricPlot3D[{1 + u Cos[v], u Sin[v], u}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2π},
                         Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.2]]];

cylinder = ParametricPlot3D[{1 + Cos[v], Sin[v], u}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2π},
                            Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.2]]];

frames = Table[

      triangle1 = ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], v}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1 - u},
                          Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.8]]];

      triangle2 = ParametricPlot3D[{1 + u Cos[t], u Sin[t], v}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, u},
                          Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.8]]];

      binder1 = Show[{cone1, triangle1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
                ImageSize -> {750, 750}, Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
                PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ViewPoint -> {2.4, 2.2, 1.1}];

      binder2 = Show[{cone2, cylinder, triangle2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
                AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, ImageSize -> {750, 750}, Boxed -> False, 
                Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
                ViewPoint -> {2.4, 2.2, 1.1}];

      GraphicsGrid[{{binder1, binder2}}], {t, 0, 2π, π/10}];

Export["rotation_solids.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞, "DisplayDuration" -> 1];
```

you can get the following *gif image* (by clicking on it, you can enlarge it):

[image]

from which it should be clear that:

- in the first case the volume of a cone ($V' = \pi/3$) is being brushed;
- in the second case the complementary volume of a cylinder ($V''=2\pi/3$) is being brushed.

In fact, $V'+V''= \pi\,$ which is the volume of a cylinder of unit radius and height.

Comment: That's a nice visualisation. The main reason the second volume is larger is that the wider part of the triangle moves fastest, sweeping through a larger part of space compared to the first volume where the narrow part of the triangle moves fastest. If you imagine that on a hot day you are trying to fan yourself with a triangular piece of cardboard, it is more effective if you hold it by the corner than if you hold it by the edge, as it displaces more air.